# Removing decimals from strings

Tags: python, string, matrix, decimal

I'm having an introductory course in python right now and i get into some troubles with the task.

I have two strings in format:

```
a b c d e  
f g h i l
```

I need to get this strings from .txt file,convert them as matrix to vertical format like this:

```
a f
b g
c h
d i
e l
```

and put into another .txt file, without using the numpy and pandas libraries. The problem is that from matrix like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 
6 7 8 9 10
```

where each number don't have to be an integer, i need to get this matrix:

```
1 6
2 7
3 8 
4 9
5 10
```

and right now i can get only that with decimals:

```
1.0 6.0
2.0 7.0
3.0 8.0
4.0 9.0
5.0 10.0
```

So, from my POW, i need to somehow remove the .0 from the final result, but i dk how i can remove decimals from the strings, consisted with float numbers.

Here goes my code:

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    Matrix = [list(map(float, row.split())) for row in f.readlines()]
TrMatrix=[[Matrix[j][i] for j in range(len(Matrix))] for i in range(len(Matrix[0]))]
file=open('output.txt','w')
for i in range(len(TrMatrix)):
    print(*TrMatrix[i],file=file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution as much as I understand your problem

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    cols = []
    for row in f.readlines():
        col = [int(float(i)) for i in row.split()]
        cols.append(col)
new_rows = []
for i in range(len(cols[0])):
    new_rows.append(' '.join([str(col[i]) for col in cols]))
Tr_matrix = '\n'.join(new_rows)
with open('output.txt','w') as file:
    file.write(Tr_matrix)
print(Tr_matrix)
```

Input:

```
1 2 3 4.6 5.4 
6 7 8 9 10
```

Output:

```
1 6
2 7
3 8
4 9
5 10
```

Comment: Trouble is that first matrix still have numbers as integers and in my task its said that numbers can be floats. But still thanks!

Comment: I adjusted the answer. now it will work even if the numbers are float type. Here int just drops the decimal. If you want to round it to the nearest integer, use `round(float(i))` instead of `int(float(i))`

Answer (score 0):

Change float to int. float contains decimals. int does not.

Comment: My bad, i didn't mention it in the question,sorry. Data from basic txt file can be float.

Comment: @sasaikudasai how do you want to get rid of a decimal from a value that is meant to have a decimal? the .0 is because the  numbers are floats, so what would you want to happen to 3.4? Please update your question with this information

Comment: @EmiOB, i hope, i made it clearer right now